# Find a basis for the subspace $M \in M_{2\times2} | MJ = JM^T for \space all \space J \in M_{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$M \in M_{2\times2} | MJ = JM^T for \space all \space J \in M_{2\times2}$

Find a basis.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ and
$ J = \begin{bmatrix}e & f \\ g & h\end{bmatrix}$

Then from the condition of the subspace,

$ae + bg = ae +fb$

$af + bh = ec + fd$

$ce + dg = ga + hb$

$cf + dh = gc + hd$

Then from the first equation we get $ f = g$.
Replacing into the second (or third) equation just ends up with the same equation as the third (or second) one. And the fourth equation does not help either, since it gives $ f = g$ as well.

I am doing something wrong here but I can't figure it out, so some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The best here is to consider specific $J$ and get some specifications for $M$. For example, take for $J$ the identity matrix. You get that $M$ has to be symmetric.

Then consider the $J$ matrix with coefficients equal to zero except one equal to $1$ and make some deductions.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Since the condition states that the statement must be true for every J, a 2 by 2 matrix, then we can use specific J to determine the properties of M. Because if it did not work for one specific 2 by 2 matrix, then there would be a contradiction.

Following your hint, set $ J = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

and this leads to $ b = c = 0$

This coupled with the fact that M must be symmetric leads to
$ M = \begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{bmatrix}$.

and I am able to find the basis from there.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant.